# Django Rest API limit

Tags: django-rest-framework

when write the URL like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Post?_limit=5 it correctly redirect me but the number of objects is not limited they all show up

views.py

```
class PostView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the rest of the documentation by adding it to the setup?
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination

Comment: ok so i did follow the documentaition and edited the original post but it's still not working